# Percentage change in salary using BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Using bigquery, I have to calculate the **percentage change of salary** from the year 2020 to 2021.
I have dummy employment data. I am sharing only a few rows of it for simplicity.

[image]
Highlighted column is the required column and I want the result to be in this form only.

Formula = (salary_2020 - salary_2021) / salary_2020 )* 100

```
    My query :

    with a_2020(
    SELECT * FROM `xx.salary.Sal_2020_2021` 
    where Year = 2020),
    
    b_2021 as (SELECT * FROM `xx.salary.Sal_2020_2021` 
    where  Year = 2021)
    
    select * , (a_2020.Salary - b_2021 .Salary) / a_2020.Salary )* 100 from b_2021
     join a_2020  
using (Emp_ID ,Address,Name, State)
```

Problem : 1)I am getting all the fields twice.
2) In the result, I get only 2021 year. Not 2020

Comment: No join condition needed?

Comment: I missed out on that part. Now I have added it though.

Comment: You need a full outer join if you want to include people only working one of the years.

Comment: I'd use Emp_ID alone as join condition. (Sometimes people move to another address.)

Comment: To calculate increase, take new salary - old salary.

Comment: What if I want to include both the years ? Any way of doing that ?

Comment: full outer join. Or skip the join and do a GROUP BY instead.

Comment: It would be really helpful if could mention the field for GROUP By .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join on Emp_ID and do not include duplicates values for year. Assuming that year column has only 2020 and 2021 values, this code might work.

```
SELECT 
    E1.Emp_ID AS Emp_ID,
    E1.Name AS Name,
    E1.Experience AS Experience,
    E1.Year AS Year,
    E1.Salary AS Salary,
    E1.State AS State, 
    E1.Address AS Address,
    CASE WHEN E1.Year=2021 AND E2.Year=2020 THEN ((E1.Salary-E2.Salary)/E2.Salary)*100 ELSE NULL END AS "Percent Increase in Salary"
FROM `xx.salary.Sal_2020_2021` E1 JOIN `xx.salary.Sal_2020_2021` E2 ON E1.Emp_ID=E2.Emp_ID AND E1.Year <> E2.Year
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    Emp_ID,
    Name,
    Experience,
    Year,
    Salary,
    State, 
    Address,
    NULL AS "Percent Increase in Salary"
FROM `xx.salary.Sal_2020_2021`
GROUP BY Emp_ID
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

Comment: spb- This code very well. 
My only concern is it doesn't show a row if its value is only for single year. 
Like no records Ananya and Armaan because they belong to a single year

Comment: mp.kaur - updated the answer to handle records belonging to single year

Answer (score 1):

You might consider below query using a window function.

```sql
SELECT Emp_ID, Year, Salary,
       IF(Year = 2021,
          ROUND((Salary / LAG(Salary) OVER w - 1) * 100, 2), NULL
       ) AS increase
  FROM `xx.salary.Sal_2020_2021`
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY Emp_ID ORDER BY Year);

+--------+------+--------+----------+
| Emp_ID | Year | Salary | increase |
+--------+------+--------+----------+
|  10003 | 2020 |  15000 |          |
|  10003 | 2021 |  16700 |    11.33 |
|  10007 | 2021 |   9000 |          |
|  10012 | 2020 |  10000 |          |
|  10012 | 2021 |  13500 |     35.0 |
|  10018 | 2021 |  19000 |          |
|  10041 | 2021 |  20000 |          |
|  10041 | 2021 |  21000 |      5.0 |
+--------+------+--------+----------+
```